# Lxml is returning an empty list

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

I am working with lxml to try to get the top 10 hits currently on spotify(https://spotifycharts.com/regional). When I run the program, it returns an empty list [] instead of returning ['song 1', 'song 2', etc].

```
    import requests
    import lxml.html

    html = requests.get("https://spotifycharts.com/regional")
    doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)

    songs = doc.xpath('//div[@id="content"]')[0]
    titles = songs.xpath('.//div[@class="chart-table-track"]/text()')
    print(titles)
```

I'm not sure if it was an xpath problem or not, but when I went to go look for another id on the site, there wasn't any. Also the id "content" is what contained the text that I needed. Same thing for "chart-table-track". Im not sure if I wrote the wrong syntax or not, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried loading this page in your browser with java script disabled? remember requests will only show you the page source, it wont be able to show you any content which is dynamically loaded via javascript or ajax calls. What do you see in the top 10 when you load the page in your broswer with java script disabled as thats how requests will see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like the following to get the first ten hits (`rank` and `name`) from that webpage. I used `BeautifulSoup` instead of `lxml` library to fetch the content.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://spotifycharts.com/regional")
doc = BeautifulSoup(html.content,"lxml")
for items in doc.select('table.chart-table tr')[1:11]:
    rank = items.select_one("td.chart-table-position").get_text(strip=True)
    name = items.select_one("td.chart-table-track > strong").get_text(strip=True)
    print(rank,name)
```

Output:

```
1 Blinding Lights
2 The Box
3 Dance Monkey
4 Don't Start Now
5 Roses - Imanbek Remix
6 In Your Eyes
7 death bed (coffee for your head) (feat. beabadoobee)
8 Say So
9 Intentions (feat. Quavo)
10 Falling
```

Comment: What would I do if I only wanted the rank and name of the song? How would I get that out?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small fix to your second XPath, change this:

```
titles = songs.xpath('.//div[@class="chart-table-track"]/text()')
```

to this:

```
titles = songs.xpath('.//td[@class="chart-table-track"]/*/text()')
```

and get yourself those song names and artists to do something with them:

```
['Blinding Lights',
'by The Weeknd',
'The Box',
'by Roddy Ricch',
'Dance Monkey',
'by Tones And I',
"Don't Start Now",
'by Dua Lipa',
...
```

---

It is much simpler to use [`requests-html`](https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/) (which uses `lxml` internally if I'm not mistaken):

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://spotifycharts.com/regional')

songs_elements = r.html.find('td.chart-table-track')[:10]
titles = [songs_element.text for songs_element in songs_elements]

print('\n'.join(titles))
```

Output is:

```
Blinding Lights by The Weeknd
Dance Monkey by Tones And I
Don't Start Now by Dua Lipa
Roses - Imanbek Remix by SAINt JHN
In Your Eyes by The Weeknd
death bed (coffee for your head) (feat. beabadoobee) by Powfu
Say So by Doja Cat
Intentions (feat. Quavo) by Justin Bieber
Falling by Trevor Daniel
```

`requests-html` is also by Kenneth Reitz, like `requests`.

Comment: It gives me an error for the "from requests_html import HTMLSession"?

Comment: Did you install it? `pipenv install requests-html` or `pip install requests-html` or similar